# Displaying a PDF then closing if not active for a period of time

Tags: jquery, pdf, jquery-plugins, timer

One of my clients wants to click on a link to load a pdf. The pdf will load in a new browser window. All ok. My client then wants the window to close if the pdf is not used for a period of time.

I was planing on using the JQuery Media Plugin to display the pdf. In the browser I can have timer and if .mousemove() is called I can reset the time.r However I don't know if moving the embed pdf will call the event to be called.

Can you think of any other ways I could do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not used".  Not in the foreground?  No mouse movement over it, no user interaction with form fields?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is absolutely no way to do this from within the browser. Your mouse events will not fire in the area of the PDF plug-in, nor will you have any other kind of access there.

The only way this *might* be possible is using Javascript [within the PDF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html). But that would require you to prepare every PDF document that will be shown - if it's possible at all.

Comment: Is it possible to embed the PDF within an IFrame and then the javascript can close the IFrame?

Comment: @xandy sure, but the iframe won't tell you if the mouse has been moved on top of the PDF, either

Answer (score 0):

A sneaky way that you *might* be able to get this to work is to load the PDF in Google Doc Viewer (http://docs.google.com/viewer) and then put an invisible DIV over it to intercept interaction. Not really sure if it's possible to do that, but it would be the most viable, as you can't even be sure what kind of PDF plugin the user is running (Adobe, FoxIt, some Linux app, etc.).

Hope this helps

Comment: That might work, but if the user has any sort of JS related security, they'll probably get a warning about clickjacking.